# Unexpected Events from parainherit(enter) extrinsic

Tags: extrinsic, events, batch

Can anyone explain why this module call [parainherent(enter)](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/12879834-1) ended up emitting a BatchCompleted and a couple ItemCompleted events?  I'm unable to find any similar cases in westend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an upward message that is being executed directly. This upward message was using `batch` internally leading to these events.